# Magento - How to update product position under a category according to their sub-categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, category, upgrade, position

I have been tasked to assign product positions to about 10000+ products, making it an impossible task to be done manually.

So I have a root category with some sub-categories. There are products under each sub-category, and all products under the sub-categories also belong to the root category.

[image]

Under the Cable category, I want to assign product positions to each product according to their sub-categories.

For example,

Product 24132 is under Subcategory Marine Cables, I want to change its position to 1.

product 24022 is under Subcategory Marine Cables, I want to change its position to 1.

product 24021 is under Subcategory Industrial Cables, I want to change its position to 2.

[image]

Basically I want to loop through all products under a Category, if the item is under a certain sub-category, a specific position will be assigned to it.

I have googled and looked up the api, but found nothing helpful. Your help will be much appreciated!